# Adding the new firebase console

Tags: android-studio, firebase

I'm trying to add the new firebase console and while changing the gradle files an error kept popping up... The error message and its respective gradle file.

[image]

Comment: If you're using the new Firebase, follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: I have but this specific error keeps popping up...